# Jasmine doesn't show template content when class property is mocked

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine

I have the following component template:

```
<div class="content p-24" *ngIf="company">

        <h1 class="m-0">
            <mat-icon>radio_button_unchecked</mat-icon>
            {{company.name}}
        </h1>
</div>
```

and the following class:

```
export class CompanyDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    company: Company;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private companiesService: CompaniesService,
        private dialogService: DialogService,
        private matDialog: MatDialog,
        private router: Router) {
    }

    async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.params.companyId;

        this.company = await this.companiesService.getCompanyById(id);
    }
```

I mock the return of the company in the test class as follows:

```
fdescribe('CompanyDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: CompanyDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CompanyDetailComponent>;

  const companyId = 1;
  const mockCompany = createMockCompany(companyId);

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockActivatedRoute = { snapshot: { params: { companyId: companyId }, queryParams: {} } };
    const mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
    const mockCompanyService = jasmine.createSpyObj(["getCompanyById"]);
    mockCompanyService.getCompanyById.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockCompany));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CompanyDetailComponent, NotificationsListComponent],
      imports: [
      // imported modules
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
        { provide: CompaniesService, useValue: mockCompanyService },
        { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CompanyDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should load company', async () => {
    await fixture.whenStable()

    expect(component.company.id).toEqual(companyId);
    expect(component.company.name).toEqual("Test company");
    expect(component.company.cif).toEqual("Test cif");
  })

  function createMockCompany(companyId: number): Company {
    let mockCompany = new Company();
    mockCompany.id = companyId;
    mockCompany.name = "Test company";
    mockCompany.cif = "Test cif";
    return mockCompany;
  }
});
```

That test passes fine. Now I want to test the content of the html returned but the ngIf="company" is not returned as it thinks company is null.

This is the test:

```
it('should delete company', async () => {
    const me = await fixture.whenStable()

    let tag = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('h1');    // returns null

});
```

I've mocked the company and confirmed it is set on the class. Therefore why does it not render?

Comment: Can the `ngOnInit` be `async`? The docs doesn't mention it, and google shows some contradicting results. I would check if the `fixture.whenStable()` in the test file returns first, or the `this.companiesService.getCompanyById(id)` in the component class resolves first (maybe with some log statements).

Comment: The same issue occurs whether i use a then in the ngonit or make it async. I tried using whenRenderingDone instead of whenStable which seems the right fit. However it stillt says company is undefined in the template.

Comment: I am not sure how `whenStable` or `whenRenderingDone` work, and if the `companiesService.getCompanyById` works correctly with the zone. So I still would verify the actual order of `getCompanyById` resolving with the result and the assertion in the test with log statements.

Comment: Already done that. I can confirm that when stable fires after getcompanyid is resolved. It should work but doesn't. Company is rendered null in the template.

Comment: Last idea: what if you add an additional `fixture.detectChanges()` after the `whenStable`.

Comment: Tried that as well! We're thinking along the same lines. I don't get why it doesn't work.